# Add missing time steps in a time series with Apache Beam

Tags: python, time-series, apache-beam, missing-data

I am trying to add missing time steps (with a specific frequency) to a time series with Apache beam. The only solution I came up with was to use pandas and make a combineGlobally which is obviously very inefficent. Is there any more elegant way?

As for now I did:

```py
@with_input_types(Dict)
@with_output_types(Dict)
class AddMissingDatesTSByKeys(trans_comp.AddMissingDatesTSByKeys, TimeSeriesTransformationByKeys, ABC):
  def combiner_class_instance(self):
    return AddMissingDatesCombiner(
      keys=self.keys,
      format=self.format,
      datefield=self.datefield,
      floatfields=self.floatfields,
      startdate=self.startdate,
      enddate=self.enddate,
      freq=self.freq)

@with_input_types(Dict)
@with_output_types(List[Dict])
class AddMissingDatesCombiner(beam.CombineFn, ABC):
  def __init__(
      self,
      keys: List[str],
      format: str,
      datefield: str,
      floatfields: List[str],
      startdate: str = None,
      enddate: str = None,
      freq: str = None
  ):
    super().__init__()
    self.keys = keys
    self.startdate_ = None
    self.enddate_ = None
    self.startdate = startdate
    self.enddate = enddate
    self.format = format
    self.datefield = datefield
    self.floatfields = floatfields
    self.freq = freq

  def create_accumulator(self):
    return list()

  def add_input(self, accumulator, element, *args, **kwargs):
    return accumulator + [element]

  def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators, *args, **kwargs):
    return [element for accumulator in accumulators
            for element in accumulator]

  def extract_output(self, accumulator, *args, **kwargs):
    df = pd.DataFrame([dict(e) for e in accumulator])
    df.loc[:, self.datefield] = pd.to_datetime(
      df[self.datefield], format=self.format)
    df = df.sort_values(
      by=self.datefield, ascending=True)

    if self.enddate == 'max':
      self.enddate_ = df[self.datefield].max()
    elif self.enddate == 'now':
      self.enddate_ = datetime.datetime.now()
    else:
      self.enddate_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(
        self.enddate, self.format)

    if self.startdate == 'min':
      self.startdate_ = df[self.datefield].min()
    elif self.startdate == 'now':
      self.startdate_ = datetime.datetime.now()
    else:
      self.startdate_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(
        self.startdate, self.format)

    if self.enddate_ < self.startdate_:
      raise ValueError(
        f'The enddate {self.enddate_} must be larger '
        f'then the startdate {self.startdate_}')

    df_outside_range = df[
      (df[self.datefield] < self.startdate_) | (df[self.datefield] > self.enddate_)]
    df_inside_range = df[
      (self.startdate_ <= df[self.datefield]) & (df[self.datefield] <= self.enddate_)]

    if (self.enddate_ - self.startdate_).days + 1 > df_inside_range.shape[0]:
      df_dates = df_inside_range[self.keys].drop_duplicates()
      df_dates[self.datefield] = [list(pd.date_range(
        start=self.startdate_,
        end=self.enddate_,
        freq=self.freq))]
      new_field = df_dates.apply(
        lambda x: pd.Series(x[self.datefield]), axis=1
      ).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
      new_field.name = self.datefield
      df_dates = df_dates.drop(
        self.datefield, axis=1).join(new_field)
      df_inside_range = pd.merge(df_dates, df_inside_range,
        on=self.datefield, how='left',
        copy=False, suffixes=('', '_ drop'))
      df_inside_range.drop(
        [col for col in df_inside_range.columns if 'drop' in col],
        axis=1, inplace=True)

    df = pd.concat([df_outside_range, df_inside_range])
    df.loc[:, self.datefield] = df[
      self.datefield].dt.strftime(self.format)
    return df.to_dict('records')

@with_input_types(Dict)
@with_output_types(Dict)
class TimeSeriesTransformationByKeys(TaggedTransformation):
  """Time series transformation per key by using the per key combiners."""
  def __init__(
          self,
          keys: List[str]):
    super().__init__()
    self.keys = keys

  def combiner_class_instance(self):
    raise NotImplementedError

  def transformation(self, tagged_pcoll, *args, **kwargs):

    tagged_pcoll_with_key = TaggedParDo(
      AddKey(keys=self.keys)).apply_fn(tagged_pcoll)

    pcoll_correct = (tagged_pcoll_with_key.value
      | self.label_fn('combine_elements_by_key') >> beam.CombinePerKey(
          self.combiner_class_instance()))

    tagged_pcoll_without_keys = TaggedParDo(RemoveKey()).apply_fn(
      TaggedPCollection(
        value=pcoll_correct,
        errors=tagged_pcoll_with_key.errors
      ))
    correct = TaggedParDo(FlatMap(flatmap)).apply_fn(tagged_pcoll_without_keys)

    errors = (
      (tagged_pcoll_without_keys.errors, correct.errors)
      | self.label_fn('flatten') >> beam.Flatten())

    return TaggedPCollection(
      value=correct.value,
      errors=errors)
```

This code separates the "well processed data" from the erroneous data. The TimeSeriesTransformationByKeys is obsolete as its use almost require the use of pandas which is slow. So now i am stucked to know how to do that without pandas, as i did not came up with any solution.

Another problem I encountered was that by using this transformation and another transformation together somehow the acumulator here had an empyt dataframe and things did not work. Why does combinations of transformations in apache beam sometimes end up with empty data? When i calculated both transformations separately they worked, and actually the add missing time steps transformation is executed before the other so it should not even effect.

Comment: Please share what code you have, explain how you're adding missing time steps, and what you want Apache Beam to do instead. Have you done anything to use Apache Beam at all so far?

Comment: Just added the code. I am quite familiar with apache beam, but when it comes to time series i am still struggling. Would appreciate any help :)